# Android error Java compiler: uses or overrides a deprecated API

Tags: android, javacompiler

I have an error in Android when compiling, it tells me for a particular activity the following error:

```
..ruta\NameActivity.java:
uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

It lets me compile and execute the project but I would like to know what the error is because it does not mark any particular line for that error.

Imports:

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
```

app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abaco.appcrystal"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['../libs']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
}


dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'
}
```

I understand that it says: use or overrides a deprecated API. but I really don't know how to determine what this api is and I don't know how to gather more information about it